# How to restore SQL Server database at previous point in time

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a co-worker that accidentally deleted all the data from an important table in an SQL Server database last Friday. I need to restore the database to the state it was on last Thursday. Can anyone explain to me how to do this step-by-step. I am not a n expert in SQL Server. I looked at some videos on YouTube but none of the videos explains exactly this scenario. I want to use the SSMS user interface to do this. I don't know how to do it by using scripts.

We have a full backup with some transaction logs. When I click on the TimeLine button in the Restore dialog, I can see that I can select the date. But I am worried the database might stay in a Restoring state if I do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Restore as a new database (just give it a different name), and then copy the data from the relevant table into your current database. Otherwise all changes made since the time the backup was done will be erased.

Comment: Did you accomplish this any way than the below?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to restore in this order:

- Full Backup (the last one before the delete)
- Differential Backup (if you have them, after the point of delete)
- Transaction Log backups starting from either the last full backup, or the last differential backup, up to the point of the deletion.

If your co-worker knows the exact time they did the deletion, you can use the `STOP AT` clause. Be sure to read up on that [in the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-sql-server-database-to-a-point-in-time-full-recovery-model?view=sql-server-2017)

I would prefer restoring this to a DB with a different name first, in a TEST environment so you know you got it right.